# How to get a value from TextPainter to NatTableContentTooltip

Tags: nattable

I am trying to get somehow value of `text = getTextToDisplay(cell, gc, rectangle.width, text);` parameter from TextPainter#paintCell() into NatTableContentTooltip#getText(). I did not find the value in `event` or `cell` parameter of the getText() method. I need some condition, if displayed text is the same as a value in cell (not cutted for narrow cells). Thanks for a hint anybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't. It is a painter that renders text according to table/cell states.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although that is not good news :)